# Handlebars: How to make custom helper for sum array?

Tags: handlebars.js

I try like this:

```
sum: function(arr) {
    const s = 0;
    for(const i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
      s = s + arr[i];
    }
    return s;
}
```

and output that in table like this:

```
{{#each something}}
  <td>{{sum this}}</td>
{{/each}}
```

but in this case nothing appears, any suggestions?

[this] array contains numbers

```
50 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 5  | 5 |
60 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 5  | 5 |
50 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10|
```

so result should be

```
160 | 30 | 30 | 30 | 20 | 20 |
```

but in my method return zero values.

If I do as @Christophe Thiry show me:

```
sum: function(item) {

  result = item[0]
  for (i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
    for (j=1; j<item.length; j++) {
      result[i] = result[i]+item[j][i];
    }
  }

  return result.toString();
}
```

and just:

```
<td>{{sum this}}</td>
```

I get **TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**

Schema model:

```
const StateResultSchema = new Schema({

    electoralUnit: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'ElectoralUnit',
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },

    allVotes: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },

    validVotes: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },

    invalidVotes: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },

    partyVotes: {
        type: [Number],
        required: true
    }

});
```

this is how it look like in MongoDB Compass"

```
_id:ObjectId("5ac4e01d46fa2b21280bd981")
electoralUnit:ObjectId("5ab906612f30fe23dc592591")
allVotes:100
validVotes:90
invalidVotes:10
partyVotes:[50,10,10,10,5,5]
__v:0
```

Comment: So you don't have just one array but one array of arrays am I right ?

Comment: Yes, I think that array of array is more precisely.

Comment: Then you don't need the each helper you have to use the helper that you've created directly so {{sum something}} and also review your sum helper because you iterate only over one array.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the each helper, you have to use the helper that you've created directly so {{sum something}} and also review your sum helper because you iterate only over one array.
Look at the below snippet to see how to achieve that.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var context = { "something" : [
  { "_id":"5ac4e01d46fa2b21280bd981",  "electoralUnit":"5ab906612f30fe23dc592591",  "allVotes":100,  "validVotes":90,  "invalidVotes":10,  "partyVotes":[50,10,10,10,5,5],  "__v":0},
  { "_id":"5ac4e01d46fa2b21280bd982",  "electoralUnit":"5ab906612f30fe23dc592592",  "allVotes":100,  "validVotes":90,  "invalidVotes":10,  "partyVotes":[50,10,10,10,5,5],  "__v":0},
  { "_id":"5ac4e01d46fa2b21280bd983",  "electoralUnit":"5ab906612f30fe23dc592593",  "allVotes":100,  "validVotes":90,  "invalidVotes":10,  "partyVotes":[60,10,10,10,5,5 ],  "__v":0},
  { "_id":"5ac4e01d46fa2b21280bd984",  "electoralUnit":"5ab906612f30fe23dc592594",  "allVotes":100,  "validVotes":90,  "invalidVotes":10,  "partyVotes":[50,10,10,10,10,10],  "__v":0}
      ]
  };
  Handlebars.registerHelper('sum', function(item) {
  result = item[0].partyVotes;
  for (i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
    for (j=1; j<item.length; j++) {
      result[i] = result[i]+item[j].partyVotes[i];
    }
  }
  
  return result.toString();
   });
 var source   = $("#sourceTemplate").html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  var html    = template(context);
  $("#resultPlaceholder").html(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="sourceTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{sum something}}
</script>
<br/>
<div id="resultPlaceholder">
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't install handlebars-helpers, only handlebars. So, I try to convert your code to have only method that I output through app.js and use in handlebars but now I'm getting a error undefined propery...

Comment: Added in first question after mine.

Comment: So from the error you get there are 2 possibilities : either your first array is null either the second one is null. Try to console.log(result) and console.log(item) so that you'll see what's wrong.

Comment: I realize that you've put too many thing in you sum function remove what is after return result.toString(); and try  sum: function(item) {

  result = item[0];console.log(item);console.log(result);
  for (i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
    for (j=1; j<item.length; j++) {
      result[i] = result[i]+item[j][i];
    }
  }

  return result.toString();

Comment: Yes, I relazied too that, and try without that but same TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined is appear. I edit first question again.

Comment: Then try to add console.log("item:"); console.log(item);console.log("result:");console.log(result) and let me know the results. If you still don't get one output then the problem is elsewhere. Put that before the loop so that is is displayed even if the loop fails.

Comment: console.log("item:"); shows item: console.log(item); shows 50 onsole.log("result:"); shows result: and console.log(result) shows undefined

Comment: I think that I don't have the right scheme for your data. Could you add the json string that you pass to your template to the question ? You can use console.log(JSON.stringify(item)); in your function to do so.

Comment: I add schema to the question. I did it manually because with console.log(JSON.stringify(item)); shows me only number 50.

Comment: I get error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'partyVotes' of undefined. Maybe because I have {{sum this}} which is array and in your case is object?

Comment: I don't know, you have to debug with console.log your data and adapt the code, because it seems that all my attempts to have the same data that you use fail.